# Rails 4, Devise - after_sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, path, omniauth

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I am trying to follow along with this tutorial:
 http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

I have moved the after_sign_in_path from the omniauth callbacks controller to the application controller, so that I can extend it.

My current attempt in the application controller is:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      if !resource.email_verified? 
          finish_signup_path(resource)
        elsif params[:redirect_to].present?
          store_location_for(resource, params[:redirect_to])
        elsif  request.referer == new_session_url
          profile_path(resource.profile) # or whatever the route is for the destination you want
        else
          store_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path 
      end 
    end
```

When I try this, I get this error:

```
ArgumentError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#linkedin
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)
```

It highlights this line of the above method:

```
elsif  request.referer == new_session_url
```

I don't know what this error message means.

My callbacks controller has:

```
def self.provides_callback_for(provider)
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{provider}
        @user = User.find_for_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user) 

        if @user.persisted?
          sign_in_and_redirect @user,  event: :authentication

          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "#{provider}".capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
        else
          session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end
    }
  end
```

Is this something to do with moving the method out of the omniauth_callbacks controller to the application controller?

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

My session routes are:

```
new_user_session GET       /users/sign_in(.:format)                          devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST      /users/sign_in(.:format)                          devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE    /users/sign_out(.:format)                         devise/sessions#destroy
```

TAKING TOM'S SUGGESTION BELOW, I change my redirect method in the application controller to:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      if !resource.email_verified? 
          finish_signup_path(resource)
        elsif params[:redirect_to].present?
          store_location_for(resource, params[:redirect_to])
        elsif  request.referer == new_session_path(:user)
          profile_path(resource.profile) # or whatever the route is for the destination you want
        else
          stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path 
      end 
    end
```

The problem with this is that when I try to sign in, I expect to go to the user's profile show page. Instead, I go to the root path. Adding (:user) to the end of the 2nd elsif statement seems to have caused that to happen. That's not what I want.

Can anyone see how to set up paths to work in this context?

Comment: If it really is highlighting that line as the error cause check your routes (rake routes) table to make sure new_session_url isn't expecting a parameter of some sort

Comment: I added my routes above. I don't know what (.:format) means, but its in most of my routes and I don't do anything special to get those working

Comment: (.:format) just shows that a route can specify the format to request the response in   /my_things.json   for instance -  :format parameter would match the json part

Answer (score 1):

Devise provides new_session_path/url and it takes the resource name as a parameter

```
elsif request.referer == new_session_url(:user)
```

for instance

Comment: The next alternative (          store_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path 
) gives this error: ArgumentError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#linkedin
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Comment: its probably a typo - but I'm guessing that should be stored_location_for   -  since you're looking to retrieve a location, not save a new one

Comment: Actually - adding (:user) stops the error message, but it doesnt work to redirect the user to the user's profile page. Is there another way of expressing this requirement so that it goes to the user's profile show page?

Comment: check what request.referrer is there -- you may want new_session_path(:user) for instance rather than a full url

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: new_session_path(:user) also produces the same result (no error message) but does not redirect to the profile show page. it goes to the root path as well

Comment: right because its not the matching the referrer. request.referer == new_session_path (:user)  would need to be true for it to redirect to where you want --  You can log it to your logs or output it to the console, or set a breakpoint and have your test stop there to check it's value.  Another question is why you care what the referrer is?  you could just replace the root_path in the last case with profile_path(resource.profile) -- I don't know what your logic really needs to be -- it depends on what you're trying to do overall

Comment: I don't know how to do any of those steps. My logs just say: Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
. This is what happens when I try to sign in, so there should be a redirect to the profile show page.

Comment: If you're redirecting to a controller that requires no authentication then I'm completely lost, and explaining how to debug a rails app is beyond the scope of this answer - there are plenty of good tutorials on that on the web

Comment: It matters because if there is a user wanting to comment on a project and they are not logged in, they should authenticate and redirect to the project they tried to comment on. If they haven't tried to do anything except sign in, they should go to their profile page. If they can't get to their profile page (which would be strange) they should to go root path

Comment: I don't know what you mean by requiring no authentication. All of these options do require authentication

Comment: OK - thanks anyway Tom - I'll try to find help somewhere else.

Comment: "Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected"  -- somewhere you are going to an action that requires no authentication if thats the error you're trying to work out

Comment: No - my profiles controller has: before_action :authenticate_user!